# Error to install PM2 globally on Ubuntu Server 20.04LTS

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2, ubuntu-server

I have a VM running Ubuntu Server 20.04LTS and I want to run a nodejs program using PM2. I'm having problems to install pm2 `npm install -g pm2@latest` and `sudo npm install -g pm2@latest`.

```sh
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/mkdirp/bin/cmd.js
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/mkdirp/bin/cmd.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-04T18_01_48_656Z-debug.log
```

Ps: I tried `npm install -g npm@latest` and cleaning npm cache but nothing seems to work. The error says that this file doesn't exist but despite knowing that, I don't know what I can do or what is causing the problem. I don't know if this affects something but I'm on root mode

Comment: tried installing with a sudo ?

Comment: Yes, on root you don't really need to use sudo, but I tried sudo anyway and got the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of `pm2-web` deprecated it a while ago, so it might be uninstallable any more.

from the official [github readme](https://github.com/achingbrain/pm2-web):

> Since it's no longer possible to monitor pm2 running on multiple
> machines I'm not really working on pm2-web any more.
>
> For an alternative, check out [Guvnor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/guvnor) - a process manager with support
> for multiple hosts, unix based permissions, a far more capable web
> interface and more.

`Guvnor` too wasn't easily installable on ubuntu 20.04, right now I use [pm2.io](https://app.pm2.io) or [pm2-gui](https://github.com/Tjatse/pm2-gui) to control my instances via web interface.